# SubSonic Include Tables Alternative to Exclude

Tags: subsonic

SubSonic is great and helps me code a lot faster, but now I've run into something that I think would help a ton of programmers.

I'm programming against a huge database, but only need about 6 or 7 tables out of the 50 or so tables.  The exclude in the Settings.ttinclude requires me to enter the other tables not needed.  I would love to have a IncludeTables string array that speeds up the entry of the tables that are required for the application.

Hopefully the team at the SubSonic project already have a patch/fix for this.

[Edited]
I see that v2.2 has includeTableList and whole list of other configuration options.  Where do I set these in v3.0.0.2???

Comment: It looks like this may already be asked, but I think it's pertaining to the web.config where as I would like to have this in the include t4 template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of having T4 templates is so you can do for yourself - not ask us to fix it (not that we mind honestly - but it's easier for you). In this case most people have just a few tables they want to exclude.

That said, in the next rev I'll make the method more generic so you can change it as needed (rather than check an array - I should ask "ShouldGenerate()").

Comment: Thanks Rob. I knew we could change the T4 templates as that's part of the whole concept of the ALT.NET community; I just don't have a lot of time and patience to sit at work and work on it. I really appreciate your time and your efforts to help out the development community with such an awesome tool.

On behalf of the development community, thank you! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm no SubSonic expert but if you are using the ActiveRecord t4 templates, you can just edit the template itself.

Look in SQLServer.ttinclude:

```
const string TABLE_SQL=@"SELECT *
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES";
```

Just add a WHERE clause to the above to include only the tables you want.

Comment: This is a really simple and elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Sestocker - Thanks for that... I believe that would work, but I have the solution that I want:

In the Settings.ttinclude I have a IncludeTables variable below the ExcludeTables variable:

```
string[] ExcludeTables = new string[]{
....
};

string[] IncludeTables = new string[]{
....
};
```

Then I updated the ActiveRecord.tt and Context.tt, changing the code that checks the ExcludeTables:

```
if(!ExludeTables.Contains(tbl.Name))
....
```

to this

```
if(IncludeTables.Contains(tbl.Name))
....
```

so I made sure that any reference to the "!ExcludeTables" was changed to "IncludeTables".

It generated the classes I needed, but I have not tested it yet.

I'll see if I can work on the t4 templates a bit to have the code work with both Exclude and Include and see if I can post it online later today or tomorrow.

Comment: Still working on the code unless someone else already made the changes that allows for a developer to use one set of templates and not two separate templates (one for ExcludeTables and another for IncludeTables).